# cocos2d ccsprite in front or top of android xml layout

Tags: android

want to add CCSprite on button click of android xml layout , this CCSprite must be in front of that layout button. Please help me out

```
holder.buttonDonate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

//  ClanCastleDonateUI extends CCLayer and it contains CCSprite
ClanCastleDonateUI troopDonatePopup = new ClanCastleDonateUI(message2);

                            troopDonatePopup.setAnchorPoint(0.5f, 0.5f);
                            troopDonatePopup.setPosition(HowUtils.getScreenSize().x/2, HowUtils.getScreenSize().y/2);

troopDonatePopup.setVertexZ(50);

                    CCDirector.sharedDirector().getRunningScene().addChild(troopDonatePopup, 9999999);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific. according to what i understand , do you need to change the button when clicked. or do you have to place a new sprite on the screen when a button is clicked.

Comment: yes i have to place a new sprite on the screen when a button is clicked.and this button is from android xml layout. i want that sprite  in front of that button...???